# Why is my AWS RDS server giving me this "no encryption" error when connecting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to learn how to use AWS RDS. I am running across this error when connecting:

> Error invoking remote method 'DB_CONNECT': error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "EXAMPLE IP HERE", user "EXAMPLE USER HERE", database "EXAMPLE DATABASE NAME HERE", no encryption.

This database is using the free tier and will be for my personal project.

I tried:

- Changing security groups to allow my IP address as well as `:://0` and `0.0.0.0`
- Remaking the database in general
- Looking it up

Comment: You should turn on SSL in your SQL client. What SQL client are you using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein This worked I tried it before, not sure why it decided to work this time. Can you write a solution so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Securing connections to RDS for PostgreSQL with SSL/TLS - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.Security.html), it is recommended that you use Secure Socket Layer (SSL) encryption when connecting to the database.

The error message you are receiving indicates that your SQL client connection is not using SSL ("`no encryption`").

If you activate SSL for your connection, it should be able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Based on error I am assuming you are running RDS Postgres. Are you trying to connect to the database over internet ( I believe so since you mentioned security group opened for 0.0.0.0/0)

Did you select Public access under connectivity ? Otherwise RDS Amazon RDS doesn't assign a public IP address to the database.

This may help you configure public access if needed
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc

If you had set rds.force_ssl to 1 in parameter group, you must connect   using psql (for example) as below

psql -h $RDSHOST  "user=xxx dbname= sslmode=require"

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect via pg8000 SQL Alchemy and this was the easiest one..
FYI, Adding this incase someone like me is stuck.

```
import ssl

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.check_hostname=False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
db.create_engine(f"postgresql+pg8000://{credentials['user']}:{credentials['password']}@{credentials['host']}:{credentials['port']}/{credentials['database']}", connect_args={'ssl_context': ssl_context})
```